# change base function behaveiour

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have executed this js code:

```
var container=function() {
    //do something
}

container.a=function {
    //do something 2
}

container.b='34'
```

Here, in order to change container.a function for example I need to do:

```
container.a=function() {
    //do something 3
}
```

How do I change the function container() ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly do you want to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assign a function to the variable:

```
container = function() {
  //do something
};
```

This of course means that you get a new function object, which doesn't have the `a` and `b` properties. If you want to keep them, you have to copy them to the new function:

```
var temp = function() {
  //do something
};
temp.a = container.a;
temp.b = container.b;
container = temp;
```

Comment: Ok, I made: for (var param in container) { temp[param] = container[param]; } in order to copy the members.